Snowpark development within Snowflake and utilizing Azure Repos for version control?
I'm new to working with Snowpark within Snowflake and utilizing Azure Repos for version control. I'm seeking guidance on the best development approach for Python scripts and stored procedures.
Is using separate Python scripts and stored procedures the recommended approach when working with Snowpark within Snowflake and utilizing Azure Repos for version control?
What is the best development approach for developing Python scripts and stored procedures? In conventional development, we create a feature branch (we have DEV, QA, UAT, and Prod environments) and then write code using an IDE (such as VSCode), test in the local environment, and push the code to the feature branch. Afterward, we create a pull request for merging the code with the DEV branch.
Is there any special library for writing Python scripts and stored procedures in VSCode?
How can we create a CI/CD pipeline for Python scripts in Snowpark within Snowflake development?
What is the best migration approach (code and queries)?
